# Diode RLC represention

Tags: diodes, modeling

I have read that R, L, C, power source and Voltage/Current controlled Voltage/Current source are enough to represent any circuit component. I searched for an RLC model for a diode(any type) and could not find any. Can diode be modeled as RLC circuit or should it be defined as a separate object in an electronics simulation?

Comment: Accurate models of diodes use nonlinear equations and incorporate transit time and noise sources. See any text on SPICE simulation. There are 15 parameters for the standard diode model, and of course any model is not perfect so it could be even more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, diodes can be modeled as RLC circuits, depending on the precision of the description you wish to obtain. Also, it is to be kept in mind that such a modeling can be considered valid only in well defined circumnstances (e.g. In steady-state, the model is valid in the on state, but not in the off state --may be obvious, but I prefer to specify that--).

The simplest model you get (in steady-state) is the one that considers the diode to be an open circuit when in the off state and a short circuit when in the on state. A slightly more accurate model cosiders the diode as a simple generator (let's say, of 0.7 V) when in the on state. With such a model, this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foREOU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

is equivalent to this (when the switch is closed and the diode turns on):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBQQTh.png)</sup>

If you are looking for an AC representation (or should I say a small signal representation), the dinamic behaviour of a diode comprises at least a resistance to model the slope of its characteristic curve and a parallel capacitor to model its attitude in accumulating charge when in on state, to be discharged in order to become reverse biased.

Comment: Also I wanted to ask what would you suggest to make an universal diode model(meaning R and C values, taking into account both DC and AC, and diode types)? If I understood correctly, SPICE diode model implies list of variables from a standard diode datasheet, and these values could be either changed manually or left as default. As for specific diode types(for instance Zener, Gunn diode) the representation includes additional elements(clampers, JFETs). For universal model, would it require to combine all of the possible diode models and include logic to choose which parts  to implement?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by "universal model": depending on the diode one wish to represent, the model will have its own values of R and C, derived from its experimental behaviour. Moreover, you need a model for the DC case and another one for the AC case anyway.

Comment: Let me explain. Lets say I am writing a program like SPICE. I want to model a resistor. What would I do? I would first define 3 variables, namely R, L, and C. This would be ideal ones. But my job is to simulate  a real resistor. Thus, when a user would add a resistor R1 it won't correspond to an ideal R defined above, instead, 3 ideal variables would be someway abstract. When user adds R1 to the circuit drawing, program would ask user to define specific values- power rating, L and C values of [resistor] (http://www.resistorguide.com/pictures/resistor-inductance.png) and etc -or leave default.

Comment: So, by gathering all(at least most important) data that defines real resistor, I would create a class, holding all the parameters, and the user  would input the parameter values of this class. If I will use a resistor with high power rating, I am not going to create a separate resistor class, but it would fit to the standard definition of real resistor. As for the diodes, I am asking the same thing, is it possible to create a universal diode model such that I won't be required to create separate objects for diode types, and one model would be sufficient to represent any kind of diode.

Comment: Thank you for clearifying that. Then I guess that yes, you can do that, although you probably would need a very detailed model with lots of first- and second-order effects (which the user of your SPICE-like program can choose to use or not). Mind that mine is only an opinion, I've never done something like that and I wouldn't know where to start from in order to realize it.